# Update object value from function based view

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a django project that has a form with two buttons in one of my templates. These buttons either accept or decline an "Offer", which is one of my models. I pass a POST request from the template to the view where i have two functions. How do i make these approve and decline buttons update the value "approved_by_x" in my model?

The Template:

```
<form method="post" class="login-container" action="{% url 'accept_booking' %}">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                       <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Accept" name="Accept"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="offer" value="{{ offer }}" />
                    </form>

                    <form method="post" class="login-container" action="{% url 'decline_booking' %}">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                       <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Decline" name="Decline" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="offer" value="{{ offer }}" />
                    </form>
```

The View:

```
def accept_booking(pr):
    offer = pr.POST.get("offer")
    print(offer)

def decline_booking(pr):
    offer = pr.POST.get("offer")
    print(offer
```

The Model:

```
class BookingOffer(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, null=True, related_name='artist')
    artist_manager = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, limit_choices_to=
    {'groups__name': 'artist_manager'})
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    time_slot = models.ForeignKey('TimeSlot', null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    tech_needs = models.TextField(blank=True)
    approved_by_bm = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    accepted_by_am = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `{{ offer }}` in your template contains the `BookingOffer` id:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound

def accept_booking(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    offer_id = request.POST.get('offer', None)
    offer = get_object_or_404(BookingOffer, pk=offer_id)
    offer.approved_by_bm = True
    offer.save()
    return redirect('some-url')

  return HttpResponseNotFound('<h1>Page not found</h1>')
```

or using class based views:

```
    from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect
    from django.views.generic import View

    class AcceptBookingView(View):

        def post(request):
            offer_id = request.POST.get('offer', None)
            offer = get_object_or_404(BookingOffer, pk=offer_id)
            offer.approved_by_bm = True
            offer.save()
            return redirect('some-url')
```